# an object representing an expression must have exactly one field

Tags: mongodb, switch-statement

How can I execute multiple operations when a switch case is true in Mongodb query.

I want to be able to execute multiple actions in the "then" section:

```
{
   case: { $eq : [ "$items.unitType", "cup" ] },
   then: { "$multiply": ["$items.quantity", 8] ,
           "$set": ["items.unitType", "oz"]}      
},
```

The first part with multiply works but the second returns the error in the subject line. How can I do that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you sample data and query https://mongoplayground.net/ and share the link

Comment: Hi Tushar, I also opened a case with Mongodb. They told me that unlike other languages which allows to chain multiple operations in a "case then" scenario inside curly braces, mongodb switch statement has limited functionality. I was able to solve it by running a parallel switch statement to update the "unitType" field.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB aggregation [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#-switch--aggregation-)  is not a flow control construct, it is an expression operator.

In other words, it does not *take actions*, it *returns a value*.

In the example below, taken from the [documentation] (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#example),  the `$switch` will resolve to a value that is then assigned to the `summary` field.

```
{$project:{
    "name" : 1,
    "summary" :{$switch:{
          branches: [
            {case: { $gte : [ { $avg : "$scores" }, 90 ] },
              then: "Doing great!"},
            {case: { $and : [ { $gte : [ { $avg : "$scores" }, 80 ] },
                               { $lt : [ { $avg : "$scores" }, 90 ] } ] },
              then: "Doing pretty well."},
            {case: { $lt : [ { $avg : "$scores" }, 80 ] },
              then: "Needs improvement."}
          ],
          default: "No scores found."
    }}
}}
```

You will likely need to repeat the $switch for each field you want affected, or you might be able to get close to what you are looking for by creating an object in the statement, like:

```
{
   case: { $eq : [ "$items.unitType", "cup" ] },
   then: {
          quantity:{ "$multiply": ["$items.quantity", 8] },
          unitType: "oz"
          }      
},
```

But you would then need to use a project or set to move the values to the desired fields.